# 'Top' button is not functioning/doesn't function with Jmeter recording however the same button works fine without Jmeter recording

Tags: jmeter

'Top' button is not functioning/doesn't function with Jmeter recording however the same button works fine without Jmeter recording (works fine with normal internet proxy). We have two buttons 'Load More' and 'top', 'Load more' able to load the page with other results but when clicked on 'top' nothing happens whereas it is working fine in normal browser.
Please suggest if i need to set something. I have even tried by including URL pattern as .*

Comment: In which browser you recorded your action? Here is my suggestion: use Blazemeter Chrome add-on for recording. After recording you can export it to JMX file. This is the hassle-free way of recording.

Comment: Also Back to Top and Load More are client-side activity which will not get captured by JMeter.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam Thanks for sharing information. I am using Firefox for recording. Is there any way to capture client side activities in Jmeter (any plugin). I have used blazemeter plugin, some of the actions are duplicated in the recorded script.

Comment: To capture client-side activity you need to use WebDriver sampler. Please refer this link. https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/

You can disable the Blazemeter requests in JMeter.

Comment: Can I post this in the answer? Will you accept it?

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam Yes, please. I will accept it as an answer as able to record things using blazemeter and got clarity on client side activities. Once again thanks.

Comment: It is done. Please accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JMeter is not a browser.** It will **not** capture the client-side activities. To capture the performance metrics of client-side you can use below options:

1. [JMeter WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)
2. [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
3. You can develop your own custom sampler

Check this article in [Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) for more details.

I always use [Blazemeter Chrome Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which is a hassle-free way to record business scenarios.